# syntax error - parse error, expecting `'(''

Tags: php, syntax

I can't seem to see the error in my code. Can someone please help identify my error.

```
    <?php if !(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() == 'mar_aa') { ?>

                <h1 class="product-header"><span><?php echo $this->__('Products') ?> (0)</span></h1>
                <p class="title-no-uppercase no-search-products">
                    <span><?php echo ($this->getNoResultText()) ? $this->getNoResultText() : $this->__('Sorry, but no results were found.') ?></span>
                    <span class="cant-find-first"><?php echo $this->getNoResultText() ? $this->getNoResultText() : $this->__('Can’t find what you’re looking for?') ?></span>
                    <span class="call-content-second"><?php echo $this->getNoResultText() ? $this->getNoResultText() : $this->__('Try calling customer service: 11111111111') ?></span>
                </p>

               <?php } ?>

                <?php if ($messages = $this->getNoteMessages()):?>
                <?php foreach ($messages as $message):?>
                <br /><?php echo $message?>
                <?php endforeach;?>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What's that lone `!` doing there after `if`? Just change your first condition from `==` to `!=`.

Comment: Syntax is `if (condition)`. You can't have anything before the `(`.

Comment: Thank you @RajdeepPaul That worked.

Comment: @thismethod You're welcome. *Cheers! :-)*